# Replacing text breaks hyperlink

Tags: regex, vba, outlook, hyperlink

The following code is executed on a message receive event in Outlook and appends hyperlinks derived from the matches of the regex to the bottom of the email. The latter portion of the code(where Reg2 comes in) is meant to remove the portion of content from the email from which the Hyperlinks were derived.

The problem is that when the second part of the code executes it breaks the hyperlinks (they come out fine if I clear out all the Reg2 replacement portion of my code).  No errors of any kind come up.

My goal is to either replace the old text with the new hyperlinks, or at the very least delete the old text.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Starscream(MyMail As MailItem)
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim strID As String
    Dim strLink As String
    Dim strNewText As String
    Dim strLinkText As String
    Dim Reg1 As RegExp
    Dim M1 As MatchCollection
    Dim M2 As MatchCollection
    Dim M As Match
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim strDelete As String
    Dim Reg2 As RegExp

strID = MyMail.EntryID
counter = 4
Set MyMail = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strID)
Set objOL = Application
strLinkText = "Open Ticket - Impact Level: "

Set Reg1 = New RegExp
    With Reg1
    .Pattern = "https.+?/Operation>"
    .Global = True
End With

Set Reg2 = New RegExp
    With Reg2
    .Pattern = "Alpha[\s\S]*Omega"
    .Global = True
    End With

'make the mail HTML format
If Not MyMail Is Nothing Then
    Set objNS = objOL.Session
    MyMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
End If

If Reg1.test(MyMail.body) Then

    Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(MyMail.body)
    For Each M In M1
        'Change things to hyperlinks here
        strLink = M.Value
        strNewText = "<p><a href=" & Chr(34) & strLink & _
         Chr(34) & ">" & strLinkText & counter & "</a></p></body>"
        MyMail.HTMLBody = Replace(MyMail.HTMLBody, "</body>", _
                      strNewText, 1, 1, vbTextCompare)
        counter = counter - 1
    Next
 End If

 'this is where things stop working
 If Reg2.test(MyMail.body) Then
    Set M2 = Reg2.Execute(MyMail.body)
    For Each M In M2
    strDelete = M.Value
    MyMail.body = Replace(MyMail.body, strDelete, _
                      "", 1, 1, vbTextCompare)
    Next
 End If

MyMail.Save
End Sub
```

**Broken Hyperlink example:**

```
''HYPERLINK "https://example.com/sdpapi/request/?OPERATION_NAME=ADD_REQUEST&TECHNICIAN_KEY=AC78DFG-CTBOP-AAUIGE-DBBB-12KGLIF&INPUT_DATA=<Operation><Details><requester>HowardStern</requester><subject>MoreInfo</subject><description>Icanhas</description><category>APPIncident</category><subcategory>INTERNAL</subcategory><item>Other</item><priority>P3 Routine</priority><group>*TestTeam </group><department>IT</department><requesttemplate>GENERAL Incident</requesttemplate></Details></Operation>"Open Ticket - Impact Level: 4
```

Comment: Add each of the links created using `Reg1` to a Collection, instead of immediately appending them to the HTML Body. Append them after the `Reg2` delete step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a working iteration finished, essentially I just had to reorder a few different things. The Reg1 execute now populates the M1 collection, then the email is cleaned up by the Reg2 portion, and afterwards the MyMail item is set to HTML and hyperlinks are appended.

```
If Reg1.test(MyMail.body) Then
  Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(MyMail.body)
 End If

If Reg2.test(MyMail.body) Then
  Set M2 = Reg2.Execute(MyMail.body)
  For Each M In M2
  strDelete = M.Value
  MyMail.body = Replace(MyMail.body, strDelete, _
                  "", 1, 1, vbTextCompare)
Next
End If

If Not MyMail Is Nothing Then
  Set objNS = objOL.Session
  MyMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
End If


For Each M In M1
    strLink = M.Value
    strNewText = "<p><a href=" & Chr(34) & strLink & _
     Chr(34) & ">" & strLinkText & counter & "</a></p></body>"
    MyMail.HTMLBody = Replace(MyMail.HTMLBody, "</body>", _
                  strNewText, 1, 1, vbTextCompare)
    counter = counter - 1
     Next

MyMail.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the plain text Body property. You need to work with the HTMLBody property to preserve the original formatting.

Comment: [I think you are referring to the Reg2.test portion]   I can change the code to "MyMail.HTMLBody=...", "MyMail.HTMLBody=Replace(MyMail.HTMLBody...", or "...=Replace(MyMail.HTMLBody..." and none of these work, though their outputs are slightly divergent.

Comment: The output is the same (or very similar) to the original example in my post